# spring + Embedded jetty + <web-app> how to create context

Tags: spring, jetty

There is a maven-project, with /WEB-INF/web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>baseWebApp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>baseWebApp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and with applicationContext.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

       <import resource="classpath:dataSource.xml"/>

       <mvc:annotation-driven/>
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.blogspot.permgen.webapp"/>

       <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
             p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
         p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

The controller is based oh annotations.

When launched by **mvn -Djetty.port=9999 jetty:run** applicaton starts well. I decided to initialize jetty in code, but failed to create context for it. Here is main class:

```
public class AppMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler();

/*here must be context initialization ... */

    Server jetty = new Server(9999);
    jetty.setHandler(sch);
    jetty.start();
}
}
```

So question is: how to init context for jetty from web.xml ?
Is it possible at all, or i have to parse it somehow with using of spring?

Comment: not directly an answer to your question, but perhaps this can help too: do you know that there is a project called "Spring Boot" that (besides other things) does the embedding stuff for you ? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat

Comment: thanks, know about it, and used it for quick startup. For now i'm trying to avoid using of all-in-one solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a web.xml to configure a context, then don't  use the ServletContextHandler,  instead use a WebAppContext, which is derived from ServletContextHander and adds the ability to use a web.xml to configure itself.

Here is an example: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-one-webapp